# Jupyterlab WSL2: Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

I get the following warning when running Jupyterlab:

`Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs`

Related answers I found just proposed to install node/npm, which I have done:

```
node -v
v.10.24.1
```

Part of my `pip freeze`:

```
jupyter-client @ file:///home/val/tools/jupyter_client-7.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
jupyter-core @ file:///home/val/tools/jupyter_core-4.9.1-py3-none-any.whl
jupyter-server @ file:///home/val/tools/jupyter_server-1.11.1-py3-none-any.whl
jupyterlab @ file:///home/val/tools/jupyterlab-4.0.0a15-py3-none-any.whl
jupyterlab-pygments @ file:///home/val/tools/jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
jupyterlab-server @ file:///home/val/tools/jupyterlab_server-2.8.2-py3-none-any.whl
```

Node has been moved to `/opt/` and added to `PATH`, so this should not be the issue as well.

I cannot use newer versions due to some additional dependencies, but judging from release dates I assumed this set-up should be compatible. I installed Linux binaries from https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases.

I have closed and re-started Jupyterlab.

My Jupyterlab is located in WSL2, my browser is in Windows.

Any help would be appreciated, because, as I said, the answers I found just assumed Node vas not downloaded / not added to `PATH`.

Comment: This is just a warning for developers, you can safely ignore it if you are not building a custom distribution of JupyterLab.